# Publishing expo hangs in azure pipelines

Tags: react-native, azure-devops, expo, azure-pipelines-build-task

Working on a react-native application and am trying to set up a pipeline to autodeploy to our QA environment. I think I have everything set up reasonably well and the npm commands work locally.

I have set up an azure pipeline and the pipeline runs. It looks like the command I've written to log in is working but the publisher seems to hang. The pipeline closes itself after 30 minutes, and it only takes a minute or so locally.

So build starts... loads, npm, login reports success then it hangs. Any suggestions?

Package.json commands

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios",
  "eject": "expo eject",
  "test:watch": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll --detectOpenHandles",
  "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --forceExit --detectOpenHandles",
  "loginToExpo": "expo login -u [id] -p [pwd]--non-interactive",
  "publishToExpo": "expo publish --non-interactive"
 },
```

Relevant azure-pipelines.yml

```
pool:
vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
 inputs:
   versionSpec: '8.x'
 displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
  npm install
  # npm test
  npm run loginToExpo
  npm run publishToExpo
displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this discussion: https://forums.expo.io/t/exp-cli-exp-login-hangs-in-bitbucket-pipelines/11676/14

Upgraded the build to node 10.x and it worked.

New azure-pipelines.yml (roughly)

```
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm test
    npm run publish
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```